# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^p\binom{2n}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

By Mathematica, we find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}=\pi^2\log(2)-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3).$$

> How to find the closed form for general series:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^p\binom{2n}{n}}? \ \  (p\ge 3)$$

Comment: What do you mean by "By Mathematics"?

Comment: I guess that, if $p>3$, the result is an hypergeometric function and probably no closed form (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Adam Chalumeau ``By Mathematica''

Comment: *How to find the closed form for general series $(p>3)$ ?* - If by absurd such a closed form in terms of $\zeta$ functions were to be known to humanity, then it would almost automatically follow that the $\zeta$ function is irrational for all natural values of the argument, which is still an unproven conjecture. $($Basically, by replacing $4$ with $-1,$ we get the celebrated series for $\zeta(3),$ which Apery famously used to [prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_theorem) its irrationality$).$

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4x)^n}{n^2{{2n}\choose n}}=2\arcsin^2(\sqrt{x}).$$
Hence, for $p=3$ we have the integral form
$$\sum\limits\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}=\int_{0}^1\frac{2\arcsin^2(\sqrt{x})}{x}\,dx.$$
and you should  be able to recover the result $\pi^2\ln(2)-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)$.

As regards the case $p=4$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^4\binom{2n}{n}}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}\int_{x=0}^t\frac{2\arcsin^2(\sqrt{x})}{x}\,dx\,dt$$
which, according to ykcaZ's comment below, leads to
$$8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\ln^2(\sin x)dx$$
that is equal to
$$8\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\ln^4(2)+\frac{2\pi^2}{3}\ln^2(2)-\frac{19\pi^4}{360}$$
(see [tough definite integral: $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\ln^2(\sin x)~dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640940/tough-definite-integral-int-0-frac-pi2x-ln2-sin-xdx) ).

More generally, for $p\geq 2$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^p\binom{2n}{n}}
=\frac{(-2)^p}{(p-2)!}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\ln^{p-2}(\sin x)\,dx.$$

Look through the paper [Sums of reciprocals of the central binomial coefficients](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf) by R. Sprugnoli for more references. See also  [On binomial sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k\,\binom {2n}n}$ and log sine integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213038/on-binomial-sums-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nk-binom-2nn-and-log-sine-in)

Comment: Thanks for the link and $\to +1$

Comment: For $p=4$ we easily get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^4\binom{2n}{n}}=-8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\ln^2(\sin x)dx$$
So I can bet there will be a closed form.

Comment: So we have some kind of closed form. See my edit.

Comment: You may like this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278448/on-closed-forms-for-the-binomial-sum-sum-n-1-infty-fracznnp-binom).

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the following representation 
$$\sf 2\arcsin^2z=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac {(2z)^{2n}}{n^2\binom {2n}n}, \ z\in[-1,1]$$
Which  gives integrating once with respect to $\sf z$ from $\sf 0$ to $\sf x$:
$$\sf 4\int_0^x \frac{\arcsin^2 z}{z}dz =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^3 \binom{2n}{n}}$$
So the sum can be written as
$$\sf S_3=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}=4\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin^2 t}{t}dt$$
Now let $\sf t=\sin x$ and integrate by parts in order to get:
$$\sf S_3=4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\cot xdx=-8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}  x\ln(\sin x)dx$$
Also we can use the fourier series of log sine 
$$\sf S_3=8\ln 2 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} xdx+8\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\cos(2nx)dx$$
The second integral is easily doable integrating by parts, thus:
$$\sf S_3=\pi^2 \ln 2+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n-1}{n^3} = \boxed{\pi^2\ln 2 -\frac72\zeta(3)}$$

---

For higher $p$ things will get quite complicate, but the approach is the same. For case $p=4$ we have:
$$\sf \frac{4}{x}\int_0^x \frac{\arcsin^2 z}{z}dz =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n}x^{2n-1}}{n^3 \binom{2n}{n}}$$
And integrating once again produces
$$\sf  8\int_0^t\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \frac{\arcsin^2 z}{z}dzdx =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n}t^{2n}}{n^4 \binom{2n}{n}}$$
$$\sf \Rightarrow S_4=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n}}{n^4 \binom{2n}{n}}=8\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \frac{\arcsin^2 z}{z}dzdx$$
$$\sf =8\int_0^1\int_z^1 \frac{1}{x}\frac{\arcsin^2 z}{z}dx dz=-8\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin^2 z \ln z}{z}dz$$
Set $z=\sin x$ and integrate by parts to get
$$\sf S_4=-8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \ln(\sin x)\cot x dx=8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\ln^2(\sin x)dx$$
$$=\boxed{8\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)+\frac13\ln^42 +4\zeta(2)\ln^2 2-\frac{19}{4}\zeta(4)}$$
See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1874534p12729513) for the above integral.

---

Or for $p=5$ we have by the same approach:
$$\sf 8\int_0^y\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \frac{\arcsin^2 z}{z}dzdxdt =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n}y^{2n}}{n^5 \binom{2n}{n}}$$
$$\sf \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n}}{n^5 \binom{2n}{n}}=8\int_0^1 \int_z^1\int_z^1 \frac{\arcsin^2 z}{xtz}dxdtdz=8\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin^2 z\ln^2 z}{z}dz$$
$$\sf \overset{z=\sin x}=8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x^2\ln^2(\sin x)\cot x dx \overset{IBP}=-\frac{16}3\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\ln^3(\sin x)dx$$
Furthermore [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04723.pdf) paper may be useful.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$n^{-p} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{p-1} e^{- n t}$$

I find for the sum

$$s(p) = \zeta(p) +  \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)} \int_0^\infty t^{p-1}\frac{e^{- t/2} }{( 1-e^{-t} )^{\frac{3}{2}}}  \arcsin(e^{-t/2})$$