# On closed forms for the binomial sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^p\,\binom {2n}n}$ for general $p$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Define the function,

$$A_p(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^p\,\binom {2n}n}$$

I've asked about the special case $z=1$ of this function before. At the end of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213038/on-binomial-sums-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nk-binom-2nn-and-log-sine-in), we find for $p\geq 2$ a closed-form in terms of a log sine integral. A variant is,

$$A_p(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p\,\binom {2n}n} = \frac{(-2)^{p}}{(p-2)!}\int_0^{\color{red}{\pi/6}} x\,\ln^{p-2}\big(\sqrt4\sin x\big)dx\tag1$$

and some experimentation shows,

$$A_p(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^p\,\binom {2n}n} = \frac{(-2)^{p}}{(p-2)!}\int_0^{\color{red}{\pi/4}} x\,\ln^{p-2}\big(\sqrt2\sin x\big)dx\tag2$$

However, [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249391/closed-form-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac4nnp-binom2nn) is about the case $z=4$ and we have the similar,

$$A_p(4)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n^p\binom{2n}{n}}
=\frac{(-2)^p}{(p-2)!}\int_0^{\color{red}{\pi/2}}  x\ln^{p-2}(\sin x)\,dx\tag3$$

> **Q:** **What is the formula for $A_p(3)$?** And what other $A_p(z)$ are formulas (whether as log sine integrals or other) known for ***general*** $p$?

***Edit***: As I suspected, there is a formula for $z=3$. Courtesy of **nospoon's** answer below, we have,

$$A_p(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n^p\binom{2n}{n}}
=\frac{(-2)^p}{(p-2)!}\int_0^{\color{red}{\pi/3}}  x\ln^{p-2}\big(\tfrac2{\sqrt3}\sin x\big)\,dx\tag4$$

Comment: For integer $z>0$, turns out it converges only for $z=1,2,3,4$. Hm.

Comment: The case $z=-1/2$ or $A_p(-1/2)$ is discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307589/finding-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k-1kn-2k-2k-choose-k) though they have only have closed-forms for $p\leq5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, we have
$$\begin{align} \operatorname{ls}^{(1)}_k(a) := 
\int_0^a x \, \ln \left( \frac{\sin x}{\sin a} \right)^{k-1} \, \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \sin a \int_0^1 \dfrac{\sin^{-1}( x \, \sin a)}{\sqrt{1-x^2 \sin^2 a}} \, \ln(x)^{k-1}\, \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \sin a \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2 x \sin a)^{2n-1}}{n \binom{2n}{n}}\, \ln(x)^{k-1}\, \mathrm{d}x
\\&= (k-1)! \,(-2)^{-k-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2 \sin a)^{2n}}{n^{k+1} \binom{2n}{n}}
\end{align}$$
If we define 
$$\operatorname{ls}_k(a) := 
\int_0^a  \ln \left( \frac{\sin x}{\sin a} \right)^{k-1} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$
we may note that your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213038/on-binomial-sums-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nk-binom-2nn-and-log-sine-in) establishes closed forms in term of zeta functions for $$\frac{\pi}{6} \operatorname{ls}_k\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)- \operatorname{ls}^{(1)}_k\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$ for $k \in {1,2,3,4,5,6,8}.$

Comment: I suspected that $\sin(\pi/m)$ was involved, and tested various possibilities. But didn't check its _reciprocal_.

Answer (score 4):

Hoping that you enjoy hypergeometric functions,
$$ A_p(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^p\,\binom {2n}n}=\frac{z}{2} \, \, _{p+1}F_p\left(1,\cdots,1;\frac{3}{2},2,\cdots,2;\frac{z}{4}\right)$$ and what you wrote in comments is correct.

Comment: Yes, I enjoy them. But nospoon gave a delicious serving of integrals in his answer. :)

Comment: Note also the similar relation, $$ B_p(z)=\sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^\infty \frac{\binom {2n}n}{(2n+1)^p}z^n=\, _{p+1}F_p\left(\frac12,\cdots,\frac12;\frac32,\cdots,\frac32;4z\right)$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. It is amazing to see how many hypergeometric functions came on board this week.